# Eclipse CDT c project setup for a specific structure

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

i recently moved to a C project and i want to use eclipse CDT as my IDE. The project layout is a bit annoying. the header files are located

> main_component/sub_comonent/**include**/ folder

However, in the c source file. they are referenced as `#inlcude<main/subcomonent/sample.h>.`

In eclipse, if i put include folder into my path, but in the source file will be referenced as `#inlcude<sample.h>` instead of `#inlcude<main/subcomonent/sample.h>.`

if i put the root of project into the path the real path will be `#inlcude<main/subcomonent/includesample.h>` instead of `#inlcude<main/subcomonent/sample.h>.`

so how can i configure eclipse to just have`#inlcude<main/subcomonent/sample.h>.`

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no better way. I finally decided to copy all the header files out to one folder by a bash.